# Cakephp Pagination in DropDown?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0, form-helpers

I'm looking for a way, to handle the Pagination-options in a **dropdown menu.**

I'd like my users to select the sorting order in the same form with my filtering options, so when they hit "Send", pagination-order is already set.orm

e.g. like:

```
$this->Form->input('paginationorder',array(
        'label' => 'order',
        'options' => array(
           'sort:id/direction:desc' => 'New Items, desc',
           'sort:id/direction:asc' => 'New Items,asc',
            ),
        'div' => false                 
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(function() {
       $('#sort-properties').change(function() {   // replace the ID_OF_YOUR_SELECT_BOX with the id to your select box given by Cake
           var price = $(this).val();
           window.location = baseUrl + 'properties/property_view/'+price;
        });
    });



<?php

echo $this->Form->input('orderby', array(
    'id' => 'sort-properties',
    'options' => array(
        'sort:sale_rent_price/direction:asc' => 'Sort by Price Low to High',
        'sort:sale_rent_price/direction:desc' => 'Sort by Price High to Low',
        'sort:created/direction:asc' => 'Sort by Date Old to New',
        'sort:created/direction:desc' => 'Sort by Date New to Old'

    ),
    'label' => false,
    'empty' => 'Default Order'
));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the values of the options to e.g. fieldname.desc, like :

```
$this->Form->input('paginationorder',array(
        'label' => 'order',
        'options' => array(
           'id.desc' => 'New Items, desc',
           'id.asc' => 'New Items,asc',
            ),
        'div' => false                 
        )
    );
```

Afterwards in the controller put the values to an array via the explode method:

```
$order = explode(".", $this->request->data['Model']['field']);
```

then you can use the values in your find condition, like:

```
$result = $this->Model->find('all', array(
    'order' => array( $order[0] => $order[1] )
));
```

There is propably a more elegant way to make this, but this should work.